# aligning partition boundaries of already installed system

Tags: linux, qemu, fdisk, parted, partition-alignment

I have qemu raw disk which includes two partitions. The second partition is not aligned according to ssd principles. I will move this into Smartcloud environment and they suggest aligning according to 4k boundaries.

How can I change starting cylinder to a multiple of 8 without reinstalling and on easiest way?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 103.0 GB, 103080263680 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12532 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          25      200781   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              26       12533   100463507+  83  Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Cylinders and Heads are irrelevant in this day and age. Stop using the DOS Compatability mode.

Turn DOS Compatability mode off with the '-c' option when you run fdisk.

DOS is dead, let it rest in peace.

Comment: This is Centos 5 anaconda installer. Do you have any recommendation for correction without reinstalling or free-erase-create-fill operations?

Comment: Yes, my recommendation is to use the ServerFault search function to look for questions that already deal with your issue. Your question has probably been asked about 100 times in various ways.